# Converting GregorianCalendar to Date on day of DST loses an hour?

Tags: java, date

I'm troubleshooting an issue with converting a GregorianCalendar that only represents the current date (ie// 2013-03-10 00:00:00) to a java.util.Date object. The idea behind this test is to take two dates - one with only the current date, and one with only the current time (ie// 1970-01-01 12:30:45), and combine them into one date representing the Date and Time (2013-03-10 12:30:45).

On the day when the DST switch occured, the test failed - because converting the GregorianCalendar to a date object (Date date = dateCal.getTime(); in the code below) lost an hour and thus rolled back to (2013-03-09 23:00:00). How can I make this not happen?

```
public static Date addTimeToDate(Date date, Date time) {
    if (date == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("date cannot be null");
    } else if (time == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("time cannot be null");
    } else {
        Calendar timeCal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        timeCal.setTime(time);

        long timeMs = timeCal.getTimeInMillis() + timeCal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + timeCal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
        return addMillisecondsToDate(date, timeMs);
    }
}


@Test
public void testAddTimeToDate() {
    Calendar expectedCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar dateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    dateCal.clear();
    dateCal.set(expectedCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), expectedCal.get(Calendar.MONTH), expectedCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    Calendar timeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeCal.clear();
    timeCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, expectedCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    timeCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, expectedCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    timeCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, expectedCal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    timeCal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, expectedCal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    Date expectedDate = expectedCal.getTime();
    Date date = dateCal.getTime();
    Date time = timeCal.getTime();

    Date actualDate = DateUtil.addTimeToDate(date, time);

    assertEquals(expectedDate, actualDate);
}
```

Comment: `Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE).getTime()` without using the gregorian date is not feasible?

Comment: Why not clearing the time fields of `dateCal` (as you already did) and after that set the time fields to those of `timeCal` instead of `DateUtil.addTimeToDate`? That is: use `Calendar` instead of `Date`.

Comment: BTW: I guess `assertEquals` will sometimes or often fail because of the elapsed time between your calls to `Calendar.getInstance()`.

Comment: @Michael: The Calendar objects are used to create specific date objects we want for this test, with the purpose of ensuring the functionality of DateUtil.addTimeToDate(). Ignoring DateUtil is outside the scope of this test.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Your suggestion is only not feasible because I do not know what you mean. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: If this is actually a test for `DateUtil` then it seems behaviour on the day of DST changing is actual a test case on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you including the timezone offsets in your calculation?  when you are working with milliseconds in Java, they are *always* in UTC.  you don't need to do any additional conversions.

Your biggest problem is probably trying to do these date/time calculations manually.  you should be using the Calendar class itself to handle the calculations.

Comment: Do you think the Calendar class can entirely replace the DateUtil method? I'd like to know how, but if that's too much a simple true/false will have me looking much closer at the Calendar class.

Comment: @tamuren - yes, this is the whole _point_ of the class, e.g. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29

Comment: I tried using Calendar for this purpose, but simply adding the two calendars together did not compensate for the change in zone_offset so the result was still off by 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

I tried and did not get a difference. Even varied locale, and substituted GregorianCalendar with Calendar..

Used:

```
private static Date addMillisecondsToDate(Date date, long timeMs) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + timeMs);
}
```

The upcoming Java 8 has better date/time support.

Comment: If you use a Date representing March 10th at midnight, a date representing any time from epoch past 2AM, then the result is 1 hour greater than expected. Since both Dates have an offset of -8 (if your PST), then when they're added together the offset is -7 (since you're now in PDT) and the time is an hour greater than desired

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up refactoring my method to compensate for the lost / gained hour due to DST:

```
public static Date addTimeToDate(Date date, Date time) {
    if (date == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("date cannot be null");
    } else if (time == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("time cannot be null");
    } else {
        Calendar dateCal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        dateCal.setTime(date);

        Calendar timeCal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        timeCal.setTime(time);
        int zoneOffset = timeCal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);

        if (dateCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.MARCH) {
            if (Calendar.SUNDAY == dateCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) && dateCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) >= 7
                    && dateCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) <= 14 && timeCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 3) {
                zoneOffset -= TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
            }
        } else if (dateCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.NOVEMBER) {
            if (Calendar.SUNDAY == dateCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) && dateCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) <= 7
                    && timeCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 3) {
                zoneOffset += TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
            }
        }
        long timeMs = timeCal.getTimeInMillis() + zoneOffset + timeCal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
        return addMillisecondsToDate(date, timeMs);
    }
}
```

I'm not fond of this method because if the rules for DST ever change then this method will need to be updated. Is there a library that would perform a similar function ?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.of(
    LocalDate.parse( "2013-03-10" ) ,
    LocalTime.parse( "12:30:45" ) ,
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )
)                                    // Instantiate a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toString()                          // Moment seen through wall-clock time of people in Tunisia time zone.
```

> 2013-03-10T12:30:45+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

```
ZonedDateTime.of(
    LocalDate.parse( "2013-03-10" ) ,
    LocalTime.parse( "12:30:45" ) ,
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )
)
.toInstant()                         // Convert to `Instant` from `ZonedDateTime`, for UTC value.
.toString()                          // Same moment, adjusted into wall-clock time of UTC. The Tunisian wall-clock is an hour ahead of UTC, but both represent the same simultaneous moment, same point on the timeline.
```

> 2013-03-10T11:30:45Z

## UTC versus Zoned

> converting the GregorianCalendar to a date object … lost an hour and thus rolled back

A `GregorianCalendar` includes a time zone. If you do not specify a time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly assigned. A `java.util.Date`, in contrast, is always in UTC. Confusingly, the `Date::toString` method dynamically assigns the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the string, creating the illusion of an assigned time zone when in fact the internal value is UTC. An awful confounding mess.

We cannot further diagnose your specifics because you did not provide information about the time zones involved on your machine.

But this is all moot, as you should be using the *java.time* classes instead.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

## java.time

> The idea behind this test is to take two dates - one with only the current date, and one with only the current time (ie// 1970-01-01 12:30:45), and combine them into one date representing the Date and Time (2013-03-10 12:30:45).

For a time-of-day, use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). For a date-only, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2013-03-10" ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "12:30:45" ) ;
```

Neither of those have a time zone, nor offset-from-UTC. So they have no meaning until assigned a zone or offset.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
```

Assign the zone to the date and time to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

Now we have an actual moment, a point on the timeline. The `ZonedDateTime` class adjusts your time-of-day if your passed `LocalTime` is not valid on that particular date in that zone. Such an adjustment is needed in case of an anomaly such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). Be sure to read the doc to understand the algorithm of that adjustment, to see if you agree its approach.

To see that same moment in UTC, extract an `Instant`. Same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).